# How do I calculate the "lead time" for feature branches in a git repository?

Tags: git

Our git workflow is simple:

- each feature has it's branch
- after work on a feature is finished, the branch is merged to master, squashing all commits (via "Pull Requests" on GitHub)
- then, we create a "Release" (another GitHub thing, basically a git tag with a specific naming, which triggers a deployment) to deploy the feature. Sometimes, releases are not done immediately, so a couple of "features" (squashed commits) are released together under one tag.

Now, what I want to do is to find "lead times": time between when the work on a feature is started (branch creation, or the first commit in a branch) and when the feature was delivered (tag creation).

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this really a Git matter? It sounds to me like you're looking for some sort of time clock / project software, like Pivotal Tracker.

Comment: When creating the branch, pass `--edit-description`, which opens a text editor so you can explain what the branch is used for. Maybe put the date and time of branch creation there?

Comment: Maybe check out the [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to see if it stores the creation date? I don't know if all reflog entries get pushed, though.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: https://github.com/Praqma/git-metrics/blob/master/README.md
We used this tool to solve a similar need.
The tool provides the lead time for every commit. You have to filter for the oldest one for each tag. Not sure if you can find pr branch when released together, but it should bring you a long way toward your answer.